# Why did my trial version of AVG stop working?

Tags: anti-virus, license-key, avg-antivirus

I have once installed the AVG internet security 9.0 antivirus. It was trial version for 30 day. After it was expired, I have downloaded the same antivirus. But when I am installing it is giving the error 'The Licence has expired'. It is the trial version. Why it is giving error ? **Can we install the trial version only one time ?** Is there any problem with my computer ? How to solve the above issue? How to remove the error ? Can anybody help me please

Comment: HEY GUYS I DOWNLOADED A 30 DAY TRIAL AND NOW IT IS DAY 31 THE LICENSE HAS EXPIRED. WHAT AM I MISSING??????

Comment: Goss, I couldn't think of a thing. It's not like the program might have stored some preventative information regarding the issue in the registry.

Comment: Easy, reformat your computer and re-install. Brand new trial period!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally cannot install a trial version over an expired trial.

Almost every trial program I know of leaves behind *some* data to say that a trial version expired and that bit of data can be difficult to find.

If you do install a new trial over an old one then it's not really a trial, it's more of a monthly update isn't it?  Why not just use the free version of AVG?  http://free.avg.com/gb-en/homepage

Answer (score 2):

The general idea with trial versions is that you use them for 30 days or whatever and then if you want to continue using them you buy the full version.